# Pull rows that have a change in them from one date to date

Tags: sql, presto

I have two base tables:

Table A

| Date | Customer ID | Colour | Pricing type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | A | Blue | Automatic |
| 01/01 | B | Blue | Automatic |
| 01/01 | C | Blue | Automatic |
| 01/01 | D | Blue | Automatic |

Table B

| Date | Customer ID | Colour | Pricing type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/01 | A | Red | Automatic |
| 02/01 | B | Blue | Automatic |
| 02/01 | C | Blue | Manual |
| 02/01 | D | Blue | Automatic |

I want to pull through rows where there has been at least one change. The Date column and Customer ID column won't ever change.

So the result I would expect from the above would be:

| Date | Customer ID | Colour | Pricing type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/01 | A | Red | Automatic |
| 02/01 | C | Blue | Manual |

We use SQL Presto, so an answer with that in mind would be great!

Thanks!

Only pull through rows that have one change from 1 row to the next

Comment: Are dates always consecutive? And are they dates at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

Using `UNION` to combine two tables into one, then we get only unique rows using `group by` and `having()`.

`WITH CTE` used to get rows where there has been at least one change. then using join with `MAX date` to get the latest rows

```
WITH CTE AS (
  select Customer_ID, Colour, Pricing_type, max(DATE) AS DATE
  from (
    select *
    from TableA
    union all
    select *
    from TableB
  ) as s
  group by Customer_ID, Colour, Pricing_type
  HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
)
SELECT  c.*
FROM CTE c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Customer_ID, MAX(DATE) as DATE
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY Customer_ID
) s on s.Customer_ID = c.Customer_ID and s.DATE = c.DATE
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm getting this error message for the last line "HAVING clause must evaluate to a boolean:". Do you know how to get around this? Cheers!

Comment: Can you try `HAVING MAX(DATE) > 1`

Comment: I have made an update using different method